# Userscript to redirect insecure pages to HTTPS

Tags: javascript, url, userscript, https

I am developing a userscript that redirects insecure pages (HTTP) to the https: version.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Secure Redirect
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  A simple userscript that redirects pages to https:.
// @author       You
// @match        *
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.onload=()=>{
        if (location.protocol != "https:") {
            window.location.href = "https:" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
        }
    };
})();
```

Please tell me if it works and what I can improve on. My GitHub repo for this project is [here](https://github.com/alphabetadev/secure-redirect).

Comment: It would work but this is something that really should be done server side.

Comment: "*Please tell me if it works*" - you should already believe that it works if you think the code is ready for Review!  Any bug ought to be a real surprise...

Comment: Um... this won't work. It'll redirect me from my file namespaces to an https version that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

### Overview

- Pass global variables as parameters to IIFE to make your code more independent and clear
- Use `addEventListener` method to follow recommended way of attaching event listeners
  Do you really need to execute redirection code, only when everything is loaded?
- I would use regex to replace protocol to make solution robust
- Try to not duplicate constant values (in this case `protocol`)

### Suggested solution

```
(function (w) {
    'use strict';

    var secureProtocol = 'https';

    if ( !w.location.protocol.startsWith(secureProtocol) ) {
        w.location.href = w.location.href.replace(/^[^:]+/, secureProtocol);
    }
})(window);
```